# Understanding this CUDA kernels launch parameters

Tags: cuda

I am trying to analyze some code I have found online and I keep thinking myself into a corner. I am looking at a histogram kernel launched with the following parameters

```
histogram<<<2500, numBins, numBins * sizeof(unsigned int)>>>(...);
```

I know that the parameters are grid, block, shared memory sizes.

So does that mean that there are 2500 blocks of `numBins` threads each, each block also having a `numBins * sizeof(unsigned int)` chunk of shared memory available to its threads?

Also, within the kernel itself there are calls to `__syncthreads()`, are there then 2500 sets of `numBins` calls to `__syncthreads()` over the course of the kernel call?

Comment: First question: yes. Second question: threads inside those 2500 block, independent of threads in other blocks, will reach to the the `__syncthreads()` point, stay until all threads in the block finish their update to the shared memory up to that point and arrive, and then continue executing further instructions. All threads inside the block will have to see the `__syncthreads()` so you can say there are *2500 sets of `numBins` calls to `__syncthreads()`*, but it's different from a usual function call. It's a barrier routine for intra-block thread synchronization.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> So does that mean that there are 2500 blocks of numBins threads each,
>   each block also having a numBins * sizeof(unsigned int) chunk of
>   shared memory available to its threads?

From the [CUDA Toolkit documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#execution-configuration):

The execution configuration (of a global function call) is specified by inserting an expression of the form `<<<Dg,Db,Ns,S>>>`, where:

- **Dg** (*dim3*) specifies the dimension and size of the grid.
- **Db** (*dim3*) specifies the dimension and size of each block
- **Ns** (*size_t*) specifies the number of bytes in shared memory that is dynamically allocated **per block** for this call in addition to the statically allocated memory.
- **S** (*cudaStream_t*) specifies the associated stream, is an optional parameter which defaults to 0.

So, as @Fazar pointed out, the answer is yes. This memory is allocated per block.

> Also, within the kernel itself there are calls to __syncthreads(), are
>   there then 2500 sets of numBins calls to __syncthreads() over the
>   course of the kernel call?

`__syncthreads()` waits until all threads in the thread block have reached this point. Is used to coordinate the communication between threads in the same block.

So, there is a `__syncthread()` call per block.